# How to show json data in table view in xcode

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i am new to ios and am currently working in json. I am just using itunes top 10 albums which to be displayed in table view i received data i formatted and displayed in table view but i can able to display only album name but i want to display all details of particular album which is to be displayed in same cell.

Here is my full code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    albumtop=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [[self itunestTable]setDataSource:self];
    [[self itunestTable]setDelegate:self];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        albumdata =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [albumdata setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [albumdata appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error in connection");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *alldata =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:albumdata options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *album =[alldata objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSArray *total =[album objectForKey:@"entry"];

    for(NSDictionary *top in total)
    {
        NSDictionary *albumname =[top objectForKey:@"im:artist" ];
        title =[albumname objectForKey:@"label"];
        [albumtop addObject:title];
    }
    [[self itunestTable]reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [albumtop count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[albumtop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Program working well

My output will be like this

```
 ---------------------------------
      Jones

---------------------------------------
     carry Kim

---------------------------------------
```

i can able to fetch single value only how can i display all the details of the album like this

```
----------------------------------
  Jones
  no.tracks 10
  price 180
---------------------------------------
  carry Kim
  no.tracks 10
  price 180
---------------------------------------
```

how i can achieve this help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: Study the documentation.

Comment: (Hint: First combine all the data into a single NSMutableArray with, eg, NSDictionaries for each row.  Then you just need to somehow communicate that array to the table view delegate class.)

Comment: (And note that the array you get back from JSON parsing is very close to being the array I mention above, if not exactly it.  That array is central to everything.)  (In other words, don't use `albumTop`, use `total`, so long as it contains everything you need and the entry count, etc, is correct.  Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath reference `total` to extract all the info you need for a particular row.)

Comment: can you say more elaborate think i ve this two values like   NSDictionary *albumname =[top objectForKey:@"im:artist" ];
        
       NSString title =[albumname objectForKey:@"label"];
        
        NSDictionary *price =[top objectForKey:@"im:itemCount" ];
        
        NSString tracks =[price objectForKey:@"label"]; i have now both album name and no.of tracks how i can save both in same index to retrieve in table

Comment: Put all the stuff for one album (mostly a bunch of NSStrings, I'd guess) into an NSMutableDictionary, then put the dictionary in an NSMutableArray, with one entry for each album.  If you have a track listing, make an array for that and put it into the album's dictionary.  It's a quite straight-forward "tree structure", with a single "root".  If you don't know how to create an NSMutableDictionary or put something into it, read the documentation -- it's both online and accessible via Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Thee label in your UITableViewCell.

And fetch each Value as you needed. It is simple fetch as you fetch value of name and put it to relevant `UILabel`. 
You also need to expand size of your cell of UITableView by following method.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

  return 80;// write as you need.
}
```

Comment: Actually i am storing album name alone in the array and passing it in object at index how can i store all details in array

Comment: @user2515863- how your JSON data looks like .. i want to show it :)

Comment: can you use that url to see how the json data looks like

Comment: okay then your array only contain name like ( Jones, carry Kim
)??

Comment: no array will contain all details like no.of tracks, price etc there r totally 10 albums but what i displayed s dummy data

Comment: if possible check the url once

Comment: @Vijay_07 - You can use the "entry" array as your primary data source for the table, or you can create a new simpler array which contains the same data only with a lot of the "noise" removed -- it's totally up to you.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath you reference the array (indexed by indexPath.row) and extract the dictionary containing all of the info for the selected album.  Reference the album's dictionary to extract individual details to go into the table view cell.  (I don't think I can make it any plainer than that.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use costum UITableviewCells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BDCustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BDCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: i know have to use custom cell but how can i load one ful album data in table one row