# customcell not showing full array data in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
This problem taking more time. i am just adding set of array values to table view array contains totally 12 values but it is just showing 3 values. if i am change row height more it is just displaying 3 values. if i reduce row height it showing all values so any one can help me how i can show all array value but my row height should be more than 100.
```

And important factor is if i print the array in cell.textlabel it printing all value but i want to print array value in dynamic uilabel so how can i do that?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [name count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileCell";

    UILabel *lab;

    ViewProfileCell *cell=(ViewProfileCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nibofviewProfile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewProfileCell" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell=[nibofviewProfile objectAtIndex:0];
        lab =[[UILabel alloc]init];
        lab.frame=CGRectMake(80, 10, 30, 50);

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];


    }


 lab.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;


}
```

THis is my code i will be very happy if some one can give solution for this

Comment: Just initialize your

ViewProfileCell *cell= [[ViewProfileCell alloc] init];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask your cell for UILabel after if () {} because UILabel *lab will be not nil only for new cells, not reused ones.

static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileCell";

```
ViewProfileCell *cell=(ViewProfileCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

if(!cell)
{
    NSArray *nibofviewProfile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewProfileCell" owner:self options:Nil];
    cell=[nibofviewProfile objectAtIndex:0];
    UILabel *lab =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    lab.frame=CGRectMake(80, 10, 30, 50);
    lab.tag = 123;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];
}
UILabel *lab = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123]; lab.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Suggestion:

Add property declaration to the ViewProfileCell class;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UILabel *nameLabel;

Add synthesize.

And implement lazy getter:

```
- (UILabel *)nameLabel
{
if (_nameLabel) return _nameLabel;

_nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 30, 50)];
[self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel;
return _nameLabel;
}
```

So your code will be

```
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileCell";

    ViewProfileCell *cell=(ViewProfileCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nibofviewProfile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ViewProfileCell" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell=[nibofviewProfile objectAtIndex:0];
    }
   cell.nameLabel.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: why you again creating UIlabel *lab with tag?

Comment: I am not creating it. I'm asking for one created early.

Comment: You better add this label in IB, and create readonly property on ViewProfileCell to return this label.

Comment: It is working like charm thank you so much for your help!! but one doubt i don no the use of tag which you creating here if you explain that it will be so helpful

Comment: I am going to display more than 5 data like name,age, gender etc.. which one is better whether to create dynamic or directly just drag labels in ViewProfileCell??

Comment: It's better to create them inside your subclass

Comment: well! if possible good you see my one other doubt in json parsing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019336/how-to-show-json-data-in-table-view-in-xcode i pasted the link here