# How to display json data in UITableviewcell in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I am currently working in JSON. I am just using a JSP webserver. Using this server, I want to display ticket number, time and status, which is to be displayed in the table view. I dont know how to display the JSON DATA in UITableview.Please give me idea any body. I am new to the ios progrmming.Thanks in advance.

`I am menctioned below is my Json data.`

> {"result":[{"request_id":587,"ticket_number":"P_1000587","email":"hars","user_id":6,"description":"","createdTime":"10/15/2013
>   06:15:06
>   PM","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":586,"ticket_number":"P_1000586","email":"h14s","user_id":6,"description":"fdyfyt","createdTime":"10/15/2013
>   06:12:56
>   PM","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":585,"ticket_number":"P_1000585","email":"har","user_id":6,"description":"","createdTime":"10/15/2013
>   06:12:29 PM","status":"initiated"},

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019336/how-to-show-json-data-in-table-view-in-xcode @murthy use it

Comment: Are you asking how to make a table or how to parse JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

To get NSDictonary out of JSON use:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

To create a UITableView read tutorials on Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Answer (score 0):

`Step 1` Declare Dictionary in `.h` file

```
NSDictionary* dictJson;
```

`Step 2` Parse JSON Data and store it into Dictionary

```
NSError* error = nil;

dictJson = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:YOURDATA options:kNilOptions error:&error]];
```

`Step 3` User following TableView Methods to fill your data and display it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    // Display Ticket_number in Text Field of TableView Cell
    [cell.textLabel setText:[[[dictJson objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ticket_number"]];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return Number of Objects in Result
    return [[dictJson objectForKey:@"result"] count];
}
```